# Problema con strrev(); para saber si una frase es palíndromo en C

Tags: c, string

Tengo un pequeño problema con este código, sirve para saber si lo que introduces por teclado es un palíndromo (se lee igual del derecho que del revés).

Solo lo es parcialmente, si cambias una letra de lo introducido este se vuelve un palindromo.

El código funciona correctamente hasta cierto punto. Al final, en el `printf("%s",strrev(palindromo);` por alguna razón le da la vuelta pero el primer elemento del string no lo imprime o lo imprime de forma errónea.

```
void espacios(char temp[],int b){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        if(temp[i]==' ')
        {
            for(j=i; j<b; j++)
            {
                temp[j]=temp[j+1];
            }
        b--;
        }
    }
}
```

Esta función es para eliminar los espacios del string, uso una variable temporal para que no se vea afectada la variable `palindromo`.

```
int main()
{
    char palindromo[100],temp[100];
    int i,j,longitud,cambios=0;
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(palindromo);
    longitud=strlen(palindromo);
    for(i=0;i<=sizeof(palindromo);i++){
        temp[i]=palindromo[i];
    }
    longitud=strlen(palindromo);
    espacios(temp,longitud);
    longitud=strlen(temp);
    for(i=0,j=(longitud-1);i<longitud,j>=0;j--,i++){
        if(temp[i]!=temp[j]){
            cambios++;
        }
    }
    if(cambios==1){
        printf("la frase introducida es parcialmente un palindromo: \n");
    } else if(cambios==0){
        printf("la frase introducida es un palindromo: \n");
    }
    printf("%s",strrev(palindromo)); // El problema
    return 0;
}
```

El problema aparece al llegar aqui:

```
printf("%s",strrev(palindromo));
```

El código, como ya he dicho, no muestra el primer valor del string.

He puesto todo el código por si he modificado el primer valor del string sin darme cuenta o si es por otra cosa. Al principio pensaba que era un error en la función `strrev();` pero si pongo únicamente eso en el código (quitándole todo lo de comprobar si es un palíndromo) `strrev();` funciona correctamente y devuelve el ultimo valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pura vida Daniel, intenta probando con for(i=0;i<sizeof(palindromo)/sizeof(char);i++) o for(i=0;i<longitud;i++). El uso sizeof(palindromo) "podria estar afectando el comportamiento" esperado, ya que este devuelve el tamaño en bytes de la estructura. (1 byte por cada char)

Comment: gracias por comentar, he intentado lo que tu has dicho pero no me ha funcionado :( . He acabado usando la función strcpy(temp,palindromo; en vez del for para igualar la cadena temp a palindromo y de esa forma el código funciona correctamente

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## El error

El código tiene un error de *off by 1*, es decir, un bucle se ejecuta una vez más de lo que debería.

Se trata de este bucle:

```
for(i=0;i<=sizeof(palindromo);i++){
    temp[i]=palindromo[i];

}
```

El `sizeof(palindromo)` te retorna el tamaño en bytes reservado para la variable `palindromo` y ya que has declarado ésta como un array de 100 char, el resultado será 100 bytes. Pero las posiciones del array en realidad van desde la `0` hasta la `99`, por lo que la condición del `for` debería ser `i<sizeof(palindromo)`, en lugar de `i<=sizeof(palindromo)`.

## ¿Por qué eso cambia la primera letra de `palindromo`?

Como consecuencia el bucle se repite 101 veces en lugar de 100. En la última iteración estás copiando a la posición 100 de la variable `temp` la posición 100 de la variable `palindromo`. Estas posiciones en realidad están ya fuera de los correspondientes arrays.

Por el orden en que has declarado las variables, resulta que justo después de que termine el array `temp`, comienza el array `palindromo`, ya que las variables locales se guardan en la pila en orden inverso a como se han declarado.

Así que cuando "te sales por 1" del array `temp`, en realidad "entras" por el inicio del array `palindromo`. Por consiguiente, cuando escribes algo en la posición 100 de `temp`, estás en realidad sobeescribiendo la posición 0 de `palindromo`. Eso explica que el primer caracter "salga mal".

En concreto lo que escribes en esa posición es lo que lees de `palindromo[100]`, el cual tampoco existe porque te has salido también de este array. Pero en este caso (por ser `palindromo` la primera variable de la función) no sabemos qué hay más allá. Será otra dirección dentro de la pila que no corresponde a ninguna de tus variables locales. Posiblemente sea la dirección de retorno, que puede ser diferente en cada ejecución lo que explicaría que el primer carácter de `palindromo` cambie por un valor "aleatorio" diferente cada vez.

Cuando usas `strcpy()` el problema se arregla, porque esta función itera sólo hasta encontrar el terminador de cadena. No te copiará 100 caracteres, sino sólo tantos como indique `strlen(palindromo)`, cosa que también podrías haber usado tú en lugar del `sizeof()`. En este caso sí que tendrías que poner el `<=` pues hay que copiar un carácter más: el terminador.

## Nota adicional

La condición `cambios==1` nunca será cierta. El número de cambios mínimo es 2, ya que a la hora de verificar el palíndromo recorres la cadena entera desde el inicio hasta el final con `i`, y desde el final al principio con `j`. Si un caracter no coincide, es decir, si `temp[i]!=temp[j]`, lo contarás dos veces, cuando `j` e `i` intercambien sus valores en una iteración futura.

Answer (score 1):

más allá del error al manejar los arrays, como veo que estás aprendiendo, te recomiendo utilizar una solución recursiva, la cual es mucho más clara que una iterativa y es mucho más fácil de entender:

```
int es_palindromo(const char *str, int i, int j, int cambios) {
  // better safe than sorry (null or empty)
  if (!str || !*str) return cambios;

  // paso base, i=j
  if (i == j) {
    return cambios; // es palindromo si cambios = 0
  }

  // si los caracteres son iguales, puede llegar a ser palindromos
  // asi que en la llamada recursiva no le sumo nada a `cambios`
  if (str[i] != str[j]) {
    return es_palindromo(str, i+1, j-1, cambios);
  }

  // caracteres no son iguales, sumo 1 a `cambios`
  return es_palindromo(str, i+1, j-1, cambios + 1);
}
```

Y, desde tu main, la puedes llamar así:

```
char palindromo[100];
gets(palindromo);
int cambios = es_palindromo(palindromo, 0, strlen(palindromo)-1, 0);
if(cambios == 0) {
  // es palindromo
} else if (cambios == 1) {
  // casi palindromo
} else {
  // no es palindromo
}
```

Esto te permitirá ahorrar en variables temporales y manejos locos de variables que no necesitás.

*Nota:* Vale la pena aclarar que `gets` es una función peligrosa por ser propensa a errores de tipo "buffer overflow", por lo que su uso debería estar acotado únicamente al ambiente académico.

**Update:** Por supuesto que la versión recursiva se puede transformar sin problemas en una versión iterativa (en este caso es bastante simple, pero hay problemas que son mas complicados):

```
int es_palindromo_iter(const char *str) {
  if (!str || !*str) return 0;

  int cambios = 0;

  for (int i =0, j = strlen(str)-1; i != j; ++i, --j) {
    if (str[i] != str[j]) {
      ++cambios;
    }
  }

  return cambios;
}
```